# Dynamically setting a link's target does nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of writing a webpage (in PHP, though this problem does not involve PHP itself) that stores URLs and lets you apply tags to them, thus letting you search for URLs by tags.

I tried to add the capacity to set a checkbox to define whether the URLs will open in new tabs or the same tab by default with a bunch of JavaScript and a cookie. The checkbox properly retains its state between page loadings, but none of the links are ever given target="_blank".

I've given all the URLs the "outbound" class, and am using the slightly undocumented document.getElementsByClassName() function to grab all the links with this class, and I've verified that this part works, as it is returning an array of Links the same size as the number of URLs on the page.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
function onload() {
    newtab = readCookie("newtab");
    if (newtab == null) {
        createCookie("newtab", "true");
        newtab = "true";
    }
    newtab = (newtab == "true");
    updateLinks(newtab);
}
function updateLinks(newtab) {
    if (newtab)
        target="_blank";
    else
        target="";
    for (link in document.getElementsByClassName("outbound")) {
        link.target = target;
    }
}
function checkboxToggled(checkbox) {
    updateLinks(checkbox.checked);
}
```

I've verified that 'target' is correctly set in updateLinks() before it loops through all the links. Does anybody have a suggestion as to what could be failing?

I've tested this on Google Chrome (my primary browser) and Firefox, and it hasn't worked properly on either.
(oddly enough, Firefox gives me a "too much recursion" error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link in your for in loop doesn't refer to the object, it's just an incrementing value.

```
  for (link in document.getElementsByClassName("outbound")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("outbound")[link].target = target;
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to use `for..in` at all. And you *really* don't want to repeat the search on each loop iteration.

Comment: Agreed, but nonetheless it solves what he's been struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues there, not least that you're not actually setting `target` on the element at all (you're setting it on a temporary string; details below).

I'd strongly recommend against using `for..in` on a `NodeList`, which is what you're doing here:

```
for (link in document.getElementsByClassName("outbound")) {
```

`for..in` loops through all the enumerable properties of an object. (And `link` will be the property *name*, not the property *value*, regardless.) I'd walk it explicitly:

```
var index, list;
list = document.getElementsByClassName("outbound");
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    link = list[index];
    // ...
}
```

Also note that `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported on all browsers.

Comment: Arg, trust JavaScript to be different from other languages. Oh, and what's not to like about using for..in on a list?

Comment: @Raceimaztion: The way `for..in` works in JavaScript is very powerful and handy. (A separate `foreach` would be nice, but didn't happen; there's the new `Array#forEach` function in ECMAScript5, though.) Re not using it on a `NodeList`: I wouldn't trust all host objects on all environments to implement their non-numeric props as non-enumerable, nor to properly support prop name enumeration (what `for..in` does). In general, for array-like objects, it's fine **if** you know what you're doing and take correct precautions: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html

Comment: Re @Andrew's comment below, he's quite right about the value of walking through things with a debugger. There's no longer any excuse not to do that with client-side JavaScript: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html